# Apache Apollo - java and stomp-websocket connecting to the same topic

Tags: java, websocket, amqp, stomp, apollo

I have an Apache Apollo server and I'm successfully producing and consuming topic messages through a java client using amqp.

Now I want to connect to these same topics using stomp through a websocket (stomp-websocket library). I set up the example chat page and successfully connect to the same topic using the java client and stomp client (the apollo admin page lists 3 consumers - one java client and two stomp clients in different tabs).

When I send a message in the stomp client the other stomp client receives the message but the java one does not (producers count is increased to 1). When I send a message through a java producer all clients get a message according to the connection display, but the messages are not displayed in the stomp clients.

here is a message from a stomp client:

> <<< MESSAGE subscription:sub-0 message-id:bad_santa-82a4 destination:
>   /topic/chat.general
>
> asfdae

Here is a message from the java client displayed in the debug area of the stomp client:

> <<< MESSAGE subscription:sub-0 destination: content-length:174
>   content-type:protocol/amqp-1.0 message-id:bad_santa-82a5
>
> SpÀBPSrÁ£ x-opt-to-type¡topicSsÀM 
>   $bd28666a-d496-4ccb-82a9-bbc3c2782b02@¡topic://chat.general@@@@@@B¸ëìåStÁSw¡postman
>   messageSxÁ£origin¡ bad_santa-82c

What is going on?

Comment: These are the connection specs under the queue in question. The two connections with 5 transfers are the stomp clients. When I send a message using the stomp clients they are both incremented, the java client remains silent

connection: /192.168.121.52:36574 3  606 bytes    msgs/sec /sec 
connection: /192.168.121.52:40246 5  364 bytes    msgs/sec /sec 
connection: /192.168.121.52:40249 5  364 bytes    msgs/sec /sec